# Unrecognized option: -compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, xmlbeans

I'm trying to run XMLBeans with the following command:

**scomp -compiler "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin\javac.exe" -cp "C:\libraries*" -out JarA.jar FileA.xsd**

However I'm getting this error below:

```
Unrecognized option: -compiler
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Can you please help me if there's anything I need to setup?

java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.3-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The javac version is more relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SomeTimes in SetDomainEnv.cmd the default code will generate wrongly so u will get Unrecognized option: -jrockit so `set BEA_JAVA_HOME`= should come at the top of `set SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67.`

**Incorrect Generated Code**

```
set SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67

set BEA_JAVA_HOME=

if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Oracle" (
    set JAVA_HOME=%BEA_JAVA_HOME%
) else (
    if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (
        set JAVA_HOME=%SUN_JAVA_HOME%
    ) else (
        set JAVA_VENDOR=Sun
        set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67
    )
)
```

**Correctly Generated Code**

```
set BEA_JAVA_HOME=

set SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67


if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Oracle" (
    set JAVA_HOME=%BEA_JAVA_HOME%
) else (
    if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (
        set JAVA_HOME=%SUN_JAVA_HOME%
    ) else (
        set JAVA_VENDOR=Sun
        set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure JAVA_HOME is set up pointing to a JDK installation (JRE is not enough).