# Eclipse JVM error when compiling MCP 9.10

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I'm trying to code my own minecraft pvp client to learn more about how minecraft works and to familiarize myself more with java. I've decompiled MCP 9.10 succesfully, opened it with Eclipse 2021-09 and fixed all the library errors. That should be enough to be able to run it now, but no matter what I try I get this error every single time:

<terminated> Client[Java Application] C:\*my user*\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.0.v20211012-1059\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Unrecognized option: -Xincgc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50PSt.png

I've tried installing jdk-6, jdk-7, jdk-8 I have installed by default and Eclipse installed jdk-11 itself and nothing changed. I know for a fact that I'm doing something wrong because I dont just have this problem on this pc. I've had the same thing happen on my laptop. So yeah, I dont know what to do.

Comment: Also, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68554693), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20067285) or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65658371) can help you

Comment: @Elikill58 Thank you so much for your help. So if I understand this correctly I simply dont need that argument and can just remove it, correct?

Comment: I think yes, you can just remove it and try without

Comment: Perfect ! I suggest you to allow for the duplicate :)